# ¿Cómo puedo lanzar mas de dos activities desde mi main activity en android?

Tags: android, activity

```
package com.example.eduarceleita.curriculumvitae;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case  R.id.button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Perfilprofesional.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
```

Comment: Por favor se más específico en lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 1):

Vale, para empezar estás cometiendo un error al asignar los botones a una misma variable cuando usas findViewById(), debes crear una variable diferente para cada botón porque sino lo que haces es sobreescribir la que ya asignaste con la nueva.
Luego en to switch metes DOS case, uno para cada ID y en cada uno lanza la nueva actividad correspondiente a cada botón.

Comment: En este caso no porque el evento onClick recibe el View del botón que es presionado por lo que debe hacer referencia al ID de Ese botón y no a un elemento de menú

Comment: Es que comentas "uno para cada ID"...

Comment: Sí pero me refiero a que cada ID debe de tener su propio case dentro de él switch puesto que son dos botones uno para lanzar cada una de las Activity

Comment: El OP requiere "enviar mas de dos activities desde mi main activity en android?" con lo que comentas solo se enviaría una =|.

Comment: Es que justo por eso en el comentario a la pregunta Le menciona que fuera más específico con lo que buscará porque lanzar dos activities puede referirse a lanzar las al mismo tiempo o poder lanzar más de una actividad a partir de botones que estén en la pantalla principal

Comment: De hecho si analizas el código del compañero Te darás cuenta que intenta instanciar dos botones diferentes por lo que se ASUME que cada uno de sus botones lanzará una actividad diferente ya que cada uno tiene un escucha de evento onClick que gestiona su switch. Aveces como programadores se nos olvida algo tan básico como analizar el código que tenemos enfrente

Comment: En cuanto a "ya que cada uno tiene un escucha de evento onClick", de hecho es el mismo listener.

Comment: Ok, fue mi culpa por no explicarme bien, a lo que me refiero es que cada uno tiene su instancia dentro del evento onClick Quién va a gestionar las acciones de acuerdo al botón que presione el usuario, por eso el switch debe tomar el ID del botón que es presionado para determinar qué acción se lleva a cabo de acuerdo a Cuál de estos accionó el usuario

Answer (score -1):

**Si deseas abrir una Actividad por cada botón.**

Primero revisa la asignación de botones a una variable, en realidad tienes 2 en tu layout, si deseas que cada botón abra una `Activity` diferente, realiza este cambio:

```
       Button button;
       Button button2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Boton 1
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            //Boton 2
            button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case  R.id.button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Perfilprofesional.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case  R.id.button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
          }
```

**Recuerda que todas las actividades que uses en tu aplicación, deben estar declaradas en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`**

---

**Si deseas abrir 2 o más Actividades:**

la forma de lanzar 2 o mas Activities es por medio de un Intent,obviamente solo una es visible, mientras que las demás estan en "background".
Este es un ejemplo abriendo 3 Actividades al mismo tiempo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Aunque Google no apoya mucho el hecho de que se abra más de una actividad al mismo tiempo pues no tienes una línea lógica de funcionamiento en la aplicación Además de que el usuario no sabe qué es lo que pasa en la segunda actividad y se puede prestar para Malas intenciones

Comment: A malas intenciones a que te refieres? 

Comment: Por ejemplo, en dispositivos pre marshmallow podrías lanzar 2 activities con la peculiaridad de que la segunda es una superposición por lo que lo que aprietes en la segunda realmente se ejecuten la primera entonces podrías advertirle al usuario en la actividad que oculta que se te va a registrar en servicios de mensajes Premium y ya valió el asunto porque fue el usuario quien dio la autorización

Comment: Por eso fue que aparecieron los permisos explícitos durante la ejecución de la aplicación

Comment: No entiendo tus comentarios, **quisiera saber donde se tiene información  acerca de que "Google no apoya el hecho de que se abra más de una actividad"**,  "En dispositivos pre marshmallow pre marshmallow podrías lanzar 2 activities con la peculiaridad de que la segunda es una superposición", estas seguro de esto? esto puede ocurrir en cualquier versión Android, lo que comentas de Marsmallow no tiene que ver con esto, tal vez piensas que porque se definen diferente los permisos tiene que ver con esta situación! **Tus comentarios no veo tengan relación con la pregunta o con lo mi respuesta**